# Explanation of plot() function in R

Tags: r, scatterplot

I am trying to plot two variables `x,y` by running the script below

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

#library(ggplot2)

#op
x = c(0.33, 0.24, 0.14, 0.28, 0.2)
#th
y = c(0.27, 0.26, 0.18, 0.22, 0.24)


plot(x,y, main="matrix",
    xlab="Op", ylab="Th", 
    xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1),
    abline(0,1, col="red"))
```

However, the plot produced only contains 5 points instead of a total of 10. So I figured, I am either doing something wrong or do not quite get what `plot()` does. Any thoughts?

Comment: Each point is specified by *two* co-ordinates,forming a pair: an x value and a y value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only get 5 points, your plot function is plotting the x variable against the y variable on two axis and therefore there are only 5 pairs of values or points.